# A mousehold plugin with delegation?

Tags: jquery, events, mouse

I'm using  Remy Sharp's jQuery plugin called [MouseHold Event](http://remysharp.com/2006/12/15/jquery-mousehold-event/) and I try bind it with .on() method, buth, it doesn't work.

```
$('#button').mousehold(function() {
   console.log(1);
});
```

The above code works fine, if the #button is in DOM, but it doesn't if, the button is created dynamically.

So, can anyone help me out? How to bind mousehold event with .on() method, to make the following code work?

```
$('body').on('mousehold', '#button', function() {
    console.log(1);
});
```

Comment: instead of mousehold why don't you use mousedown?

Comment: Mouse down consoles only one time per click (per mouse down event) and I need to console until I leave mouse from that button.

Comment: what do you want to make with that mousehold?

Comment: Call my custom function. Just like on this page, http://remysharp.com/demo/pip_ticker.html, the only difference is that the trigger button is created dynamically .. That's why I need to bind it.

Comment: onmousehold increase or decrease the value of Trading Value?

Comment: Yeah, you can say that. But with dynamically created buttons.

Comment: ok i am gonna make it and show you ;)

Comment: i got it check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/yjSjD/ making more on it ;) only increase works!

Comment: @AspiringAqib, wow, that works nice, thanks, it's exactly what I needed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yjSjD/1/ enjoy, this is yours now :)

Comment: is that exactly what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

[Remy Sharp's `$.fn.mousehold`](http://remysharp.com/demo/mousehold.js) is a jQuery plugin not an Event type, you can't bind it by using `.on()` nor any of the event handler bindings.

---

### UPDATE

I put up together a [`$.fn.mousehold`](https://github.com/aeurielesn/jQuery.fn/blob/master/$.fn.mousehold/$.fn.mousehold.js) plugin that works with delegation. The method signature is:

> **`.mousehold( [selector], handler(eventObject) [, delay] )`**
>
> - **`selector`**: A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is `null` or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.
> - **`handler(eventObject)`**: A function to execute when the event is triggered. The value `false` is also allowed as a shorthand for a function that simply does return `false`.
> - **`delay`**: A number determining the number of milliseconds to wait before consecutive triggers. Default value is `100`.

Examples:

```
$('#button').mousehold(function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.times);
});
```

```
$(document).mousehold("#button", function() {
  console.log(evt.times);
}, 200);
```

[**A live example here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JXTDA/)

Comment: Ok, but what options do I have?

Comment: @LadoLomidze, a mousehold modification that accepts delegated events maybe

Comment: that's the whole problem, don't know, how to modificate it :(

Comment: @LadoLomidze, don't forget to mark it as an answer if it worked for you

Comment: Hey @Alexander, any idea why this doesn't work with `.on()`? ie. `$("button").on("mousehold", function() {...})`

Comment: @TobiasFünke, yes, you can read the answer. it's explained there ;)